# Как выключить медиаплеер через уведомление в android?

Tags: android, android-notification

Подскажите пожалуйста как выключить медиаплеер через уведомление в android studio.

Comment: Если он крутится как сервис - добавляете кнопку, кнопкой останавливаете сервис.

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать через .addaction?

Comment: setContentIntent